# adding style to the header of the tab jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

i'm trying to adding style only to the headers of the tab, my goal it's that i want that the class that appears in the event hover remains until the user change the tab. i tried like this

```
$("#menuContainer").tabs();
$("#menuContainer").bind('tabsselect',function (event,ui){

    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
});
```

but when i do that i change the background of all tab and i just want change the header not all the div.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

My html

```
<div id="menuContainer">
        <ul id="menuPrincipal">
            <li>
            <a href="#tabs-1">Quienes Somos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2">Catalogo de Repuestos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#tabs-3">Cotizacion OnLine</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#tabs-4">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you posting from a cell phone, or is there something wrong with your shift key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally i could it make it to change style of a tab you need attach the right event and using the correct object like this

```
$("#menuContainer").bind('tabsshow',function (event,ui){
    $(ui.tab).parent().removeClass('ui-state-active');
    $(ui.tab).parent().css('border','1px solid #072fc5');

});
```

**Notes that i remove the class `ui-state-active` for adding my style**

Also it's important the event associate it has to be **`tabsshow`** because in the event **`tabselected`** the class ui-state-active it's not yet adding to the tab

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** Applying correct traversing on checking for correct children:

```
$("#menuContainer").find("a").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(
        function(){$(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");},
        function(){$(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");}
    );
});
```

Test mockup on http://jsfiddle.net/myriad/EEW2m/

Comment: @Jorge right - what's the type of element menuContainer? If it's not the actual ul, then true, no li children for that one - so using find() should manage those

Comment: @leon thanks for your help. I realize that i'm question it's wrong. Because i want that adding style to the header of the tab

Comment: @Jorge, your html isn't helping much - no li's in there, neither #menuContainer. The structure is needed to properly point where it applies

Comment: @leon sorry leon but i'm tired, and i made a mistake putting my html code i already modified s

Comment: @leon exactly maybe it's not the li style that i need to override

Comment: @leon i finally could make it i put my answer. But Thanks for your help